# ruby how to make a hash with new keys, and values from an array

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

I have an array of arrays like this:

```
arr = [["food", "eggs"],["beverage", "milk"],["desert", "cake"]]
```

And I need to turn it into an array of hashes where the keys are custom and new, and the values of the keys are the values in the array, like this:

```
hash = [{"category": "food", "item":"eggs"},
          {"category": "beverage", "item":"milk"}
          {"category": "desert", "item":"cake"}]
```

how would I do this?
thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`Array#map`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Array.html#method-i-map):

```
arr = [["food", "eggs"], ["beverage", "milk"], ["desert", "cake"]]

arr.map { |category, item| { category: category, item: item } }
# => [
#      {:category=>"food", :item=>"eggs"},
#      {:category=>"beverage", :item=>"milk"},
#      {:category=>"desert", :item=>"cake"}
#    ]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
arr = [["food", "eggs"],["beverage", "milk"],["desert", "cake"]]

arr.inject([]) do |hash, (v1, v2)|
  hash << { category: v1, item: v2 }
end
```

I used [`inject`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject) to keep the code concise.

Next time you may want to show what you have tried in the question, just to demonstrate that you actually tried to do something before asking for code.

Comment: thankyou for your input as well. both solutions work great. and thank you for the advice on asking the question, i will keep that in mind next time

Answer (score 0):

```
hash = arr.each_with_object({}){|elem, hsh|hsh[elem[0]] = elem[1]}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
hash = array.map {|ary| Hash[[:category, :item].zip ary ]}
```